# PlayWright docker image running in Docker Mixed mode on Windows 10, but not on Windows 11

Tags: windows, docker, playwright, wsl-2, lcow

## My problem

I'm using Docker 4.18.0 with Mixed Mode (Windows and Linux side by side) by enabling Experimental. 4.18.0 is the latest version that supports LCOW (Linux Containers on Windows). This is working okay, and I can run multiple Windows and Linux containers side by side, while my Docker Desktop is just switched to use Windows Containers.

But one image, PlayWright, is having issues: it will run on Windows 10 computers, but won't  run on Windows 11 computers. I have tried mulitple Windows 10 and Windows 11 computers. On Windows 11 it gives the error:

```
PS C:\Users\nl-x> docker run --platform linux -it mcr.microsoft.com/playwright
docker: Error response from daemon: hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem d9d9b26ee57e8
8be6f640a99cb173fb28e2fee9335cc44e977cce1d19d4ce493: An adapter was not found.
```

I have no idea what kind of adapter is not found on Windows 11, nor how to fix this.

I have already tried updating my WSL with `wsl --update`. And I did notice that the [PlayWright Docker image](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/main/utils/docker/Dockerfile.jammy) uses the Ubuntu jammy base image. And that I can run this base image on both Windows 10 and Windows 11 using: `docker run --platform linux -it ubuntu:jammy`. So I don't think the issue is from the base image.

## System information

Here is my WSL version on my Windows 11 machine (note that it specifies Windows 10, while it's really on Windows 11.):

```
PS C:\Users\nl-x> wsl --version
WSL version: 2.1.4.0
Kernel version: 5.15.146.1-2
WSLg version: 1.0.60
MSRDC version: 1.2.5105
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22631.3155
```

And here is my docker info on my Windows 11 machine (note that it specifies Windows 10, while it's really on Windows 11.):

```
PS C:\Users\nl-x> docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.10.3)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.15.1)
  dev: Docker Dev Environments (Docker Inc., v0.1.0)
  extension: Manages Docker extensions (Docker Inc., v0.2.18)
  sbom: View the packaged-based Software Bill Of Materials (SBOM) for an image (Anchore Inc., 0.6.0)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.25.0)
  scout: Command line tool for Docker Scout (Docker Inc., v0.6.0)

Server:
 Containers: 26
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 25
 Images: 62
 Server Version: 20.10.23
 Storage Driver: windowsfilter (windows) lcow (linux)
  Windows:
  LCOW:
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: ics internal l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay private transparent
  Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gcplogs gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Default Isolation: hyperv
 Kernel Version: 10.0 22631 (22621.1.amd64fre.ni_release.220506-1250)
 Operating System: Windows 10 Pro Version 2009 (OS Build 22631.3155)
 OSType: windows
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 16
 Total Memory: 46.83GiB
 Name: Laptop-Zouhair
 ID: 4GBS:D3DH:PT22:UVQO:ACUS:2PLQ:NSJ4:IJWH:ET4W:7FNS:JNM3:DXOC
 Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\Docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: true
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
 Product License: Community Engine
```

Comment: Is your WSL 2 fully set up and is the default version? (`wsl --update` + `wsl --set-default-version 2`). Are Docker's experimental features enabled? (`"experimental": true` in the `daemon.json`). Make sure Hyper-V and the Virtual Machine Platform Windows features are enabled. Test with a simple Linux container to make sure LCOW is functioning (`docker run --platform linux --rm hello-world`). If the basic test succeeds, try `docker run --platform linux -it mcr.microsoft.com/playwright`.

Comment: @VonC WSL2 is set up, defaulting to Ubuntu. Experimental is on. Hyper-V and Virtual Machine Platform are enabled. The Hello-World image does work, just like the base image of PlayWright, which is ubuntu:jammy. So the issue is really with PlayWright and not Linux images in general. It's just the PlayWright images that gives the error message. `docker: Error response from daemon: hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem ...: An adapter was not found.`

Comment: Would a custom PlayWright image work better? (`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:latest ... CMD ["bash"]` + `docker build -t custom-playwright .` + `docker run --platform linux -it custom-playwright`)

Comment: @VonC What do you mean with `...` ? Just putting `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright` and `CMD ["bash"]` into a Dockerfile, building it, and running it, gives the same error.

Comment: I just meant any other Docker file command you want to add between the first and last line.